# Plesk api retrieve mail password

Tags: php, api, plesk

The plesk version on my server has been updated to 12.0.18

Before I was getting the passwords of all my client as following

```
<packet version="1.6.0.2">
<mail>
    <get_info>
       <filter>
         <domain_id>{DOMAIN-ID}</domain_id>
       </filter>
       <cp_access/>
       <mailbox/>
       <aliases/>
       <permissions/>
     </get_info>
</mail>
```

Now after the update the password field is empty.

So after reading the "XML API Manual, Plesk 12.0" documentation

I updated the packet message to 1.6.3.0 wich is the version the use in the examples

```
<packet version="1.6.3.0">
<mail>
<get_info>
   <filter>
      <site-id>{SITE-ID}</site-id>
   </filter>
<mailbox/>
</get_info>
</mail>
</packet>
```

But with this packet I don't even get the password field at all.

Is this function been removed or am I doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There is no more ways for retrieving Plesk user passwords via API or CLI.